# trying to print cost total of my menu gui in tkinter. ERROR = 'int' object is not callable

Tags: python, tkinter, integer

Hi i have had trouble trying to make this menu chat bot kind of thing into a gui, i have mismatched a bit of code and i can print the total cost of all items once clicked 'Finish Order' in line 108

All Code:

```
    from tkinter import *

cost = 0

class Window(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        Frame.__init__(self, master, bg='#DA291C')               
        self.master = master
        self.init_window()
    def init_window(self):
        self.master.title("Maccas Menu")
        self.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=1)
        Label(self, bg='#DA291C', text=" Name: ",fg='#FFC72C').grid(row=0)
        Label(self, bg='#DA291C', text="Address: ",fg='#FFC72C').grid(row=1)
        Label(self, bg='#DA291C', text="Phone: ",fg='#FFC72C').grid(row=2)

        #Customer Details
        self.Name = Entry(self)
        self.Name.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.Address = Entry(self, state='disabled')
        self.Address.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.Phone_Number = Entry(self, state='disabled')
        self.Phone_Number.grid(row=2, column=1)

        self.delivery = BooleanVar()
        Checkbutton(self, text="Delivery",fg='#27251F', bg='#DA291C', variable=self.delivery, command=self.check).grid(row=1, column=2)
        Button(self, text='Show',fg='#27251F', bg='#DA291C', command=self.show_entry_fields).grid(row=0, column=2, sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)

        #Maccas Selection
        Label(self, text = "Maccas", font='bold', fg='#27251F', bg='#DA291C').grid(columnspan=2, pady=(20,5))

        #Maccas Numbers
        self.BigMac_num = IntVar()
        self.Nuggets_num = IntVar()
        self.AngusBurger_num = IntVar()
        self.Wraps_num = IntVar()
        self.SoftServe_num = IntVar()
        self.Fillet_o_Fish_num = IntVar()
        self.HappyMeal_num = IntVar()
        self.Salad_num = IntVar()
        self.Sprite_num_num = IntVar()
        self.Frozen_Coke_num = IntVar()
        self.Apple_Pie_num = IntVar()
        self.Apple_Slices_num = IntVar()

        #Spinbox Labels
        Label(self, text = "BigMac",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=4)
        Label(self, text = "Nuggets",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=5)
        Label(self, text = "AngusBurger",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=6)
        Label(self, text = "Wraps",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=7)
        Label(self, text = "SoftServe",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=8)
        Label(self, text = "Fillet'o'Fish",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=9)
        Label(self, text = "HappyMeal",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=10)
        Label(self, text = "Salad",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=11)
        Label(self, text = "Sprite",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=12)
        Label(self, text = "Frozen Coke",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=13)
        Label(self, text = "Apple Pie",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=14)
        Label(self, text = "Apple Slices",fg='#FFC72C', bg='#DA291C').grid(row=15)

        #Spinboxes
        self.BigMac_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.Nuggets_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.AngusBurger_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.Wraps_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.SoftServe_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.Fillet_o_Fish_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.HappyMeal_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.Salad_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.Sprite_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.Frozen_Coke_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.Apple_Pie_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)
        self.Apple_Slices_num = Spinbox(self, from_=0, to=5)

        #Spinbox Positioning
        self.BigMac_num.grid(row=4, column=1)
        self.Nuggets_num.grid(row=5, column=1)
        self.AngusBurger_num.grid(row=6, column=1)
        self.Wraps_num.grid(row=7, column=1)
        self.SoftServe_num.grid(row=8, column=1)
        self.Fillet_o_Fish_num.grid(row=9, column=1)
        self.HappyMeal_num.grid(row=10, column=1)
        self.Salad_num.grid(row=11, column=1)
        self.Sprite_num.grid(row=12, column=1)
        self.Frozen_Coke_num.grid(row=13, column=1)
        self.Apple_Pie_num.grid(row=14, column=1)
        self.Apple_Slices_num.grid(row=15, column=1)

        self.Total_Maccas_num = IntVar()

        Button(self, text='Finish Order',fg='#27251F',bg='#DA291C', command=self.Maccas_Submit).grid(row=16, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)
        self.TooMany = Label(self, text = "Less than 5 items please.")
        self.TooMany.grid_remove()
         
    def Maccas_Submit(self):
        self.Total_Maccas_num = int(self.BigMac_num.get()) + int(self.Nuggets_num.get()) + int(self.AngusBurger_num.get()) + int(self.Wraps_num.get()) + int(self.SoftServe_num.get()) + int(self.Fillet_o_Fish_num.get()) + int(self.HappyMeal_num.get()) + int(self.Salad_num.get()) + int(self.Sprite_num.get()) + int(self.Frozen_Coke_num.get()) + int(self.Apple_Pie_num.get()) + int(self.Apple_Slices_num.get())
        if int(self.Total_Maccas_num) > 5:
            self.TooMany.grid(row=20, column=1)
        else:
            self.Total_Maccas_num(row=20, column=1)
            
             
            
    def check(self):    
        if self.delivery.get() == True:
            self.Address.configure(state='normal')
            self.Phone_Number.configure(state='normal')
        else:
            self.Address.configure(state='disabled')
            self.Phone_Number.configure(state='disabled')
    def show_entry_fields(self):
        global cost
        print("\n Name: {}\n Address: {}\n Phone Number: {}" .format(self.Name.get(), self.Address.get(), self.Phone_Number.get()))
        print(self.delivery.get())
        if self.delivery.get() == True:
            cost += 3
        print(cost)


root = Tk()

root.geometry("400x600")

app = Window(root)

root.mainloop()
```

here is the section i am confused about and would like some help with.

```
        def Maccas_Submit(self):
        self.Total_Maccas_num = int(self.BigMac_num.get()) + int(self.Nuggets_num.get()) + int(self.AngusBurger_num.get()) + int(self.Wraps_num.get()) + int(self.SoftServe_num.get()) + int(self.Fillet_o_Fish_num.get()) + int(self.HappyMeal_num.get()) + int(self.Salad_num.get()) + int(self.Sprite_num.get()) + int(self.Frozen_Coke_num.get()) + int(self.Apple_Pie_num.get()) + int(self.Apple_Slices_num.get())
        if int(self.Total_Maccas_num) > 5:
            self.TooMany.grid(row=20, column=1)
        else:
            self.Total_Maccas_num(row=20, column=1)
```

if anyone can solve this problem it would help a lot thanks.

Comment: You have changed `self.Total_Maccas_num` from `IntVar` to `int` inside `Maccas_Submit()`, then called `self.Total_Maccas_num(row=20, column=1)`.

Comment: im not following, what do i need to change?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside `Maccas_Submit()`, you have changed `self.Total_Maccas_num` from `IntVar` (initialized inside `init_window()`) to `int`:

```py
    def Maccas_Submit(self):
        # below line changed self.Total_Maccas_num to 'int'
        self.Total_Maccas_num = int(self.BigMac_num.get()) + int(self.Nuggets_num.get()) + int(self.AngusBurger_num.get()) + int(self.Wraps_num.get()) + int(self.SoftServe_num.get()) + int(self.Fillet_o_Fish_num.get()) + int(self.HappyMeal_num.get()) + int(self.Salad_num.get()) + int(self.Sprite_num.get()) + int(self.Frozen_Coke_num.get()) + int(self.Apple_Pie_num.get()) + int(self.Apple_Slices_num.get())
        if int(self.Total_Maccas_num) > 5:
            self.TooMany.grid(row=20, column=1)
        else:
            # below line tries to use 'int' as a function which causes the exception
            self.Total_Maccas_num(row=20, column=1)
```

Based on your code, I would suggest the following changes:

```py
class Window(Frame):
    ...
    def init_window(self):
        ...
        self.Total_Maccas_num = IntVar()

        Button(self, text='Finish Order',fg='#27251F',bg='#DA291C', command=self.Maccas_Submit).grid(row=16, column=0, sticky=W, pady=4, padx=5)
        self.TooMany = Label(self, text = "Less than 5 items please.")
        #self.TooMany.grid_remove() # not necessary
        self.total_label = Label(self, textvariable=self.Total_Maccas_num)  # added a label for the total

    def Maccas_Submit(self):
        total = int(self.BigMac_num.get()) + int(self.Nuggets_num.get()) + int(self.AngusBurger_num.get()) + int(self.Wraps_num.get()) + int(self.SoftServe_num.get()) + int(self.Fillet_o_Fish_num.get()) + int(self.HappyMeal_num.get()) + int(self.Salad_num.get()) + int(self.Sprite_num.get()) + int(self.Frozen_Coke_num.get()) + int(self.Apple_Pie_num.get()) + int(self.Apple_Slices_num.get())
        if total > 5:
            self.total_label.grid_forget() # hide the total_label
            self.TooMany.grid(row=20, column=1) # show the warning
        else:
            self.TooMany.grid_forget() # hide the warning
            self.Total_Maccas_num.set(total) # update total_label
            self.total_label.grid(row=20, column=1) # show total_label
```

Comment: i see where i went wrong. this is awesome thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

I can't really explain it so here's an example:

```
#This is my own Python Grade Percentage Calculator

import tkinter

root = tkinter.Tk()
root.title("Calculator")

root.configure(background="red")


expression =""

def add(value):
    global expression
    expression += value
    label_result.config(text=expression)

def clear():
    global expression
    expression = ""
    label_result.config(text=expression)

def calculate():
    global expression
    result = ""
    if expression != "":
        try:
            result = format(eval(expression), ".2f")
        except:
            result = "Invalid Entry"
            expression = ""
    label_result.config(text=result)

# Create GUI
label_result = tkinter.Label(root, height=3, text="JOEL'S \n GRADE CALCULATOR \n",fg="#FFFFFF", bg="red", font="Calibri 20 bold")
label_result.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=3)

label_result = tkinter.Label(root, height=2, text="",fg="#FFFFFF", bg="red", font="verdana 15 bold")
label_result.grid(row=1, column=0, columnspan=3)

button_1 = tkinter.Button(root, text="1", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("1"))
button_1.grid(row=2, column=0)

button_2 = tkinter.Button(root, text="2", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("2"))
button_2.grid(row=2, column=1)

button_3 = tkinter.Button(root, text="3", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("3"))
button_3.grid(row=2, column=2)

button_4 = tkinter.Button(root, text="4", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("4"))
button_4.grid(row=3, column=0)

button_5 = tkinter.Button(root, text="5", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("5"))
button_5.grid(row=3, column=1)

button_6 = tkinter.Button(root, text="6", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("6"))
button_6.grid(row=3, column=2)

button_7 = tkinter.Button(root, text="7", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("7"))
button_7.grid(row=4, column=0)

button_8 = tkinter.Button(root, text="8", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("8"))
button_8.grid(row=4, column=1)

button_9 = tkinter.Button(root, text="9", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("9"))
button_9.grid(row=4, column=2)

button_clear = tkinter.Button(root, text="CLEAR", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: clear())
button_clear.grid(row=5, column=0)

button_0 = tkinter.Button(root, text="0", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("0"))
button_0.grid(row=5, column=1)

button_dot = tkinter.Button(root, text=".", height=4, width=20, command=lambda: add("."))
button_dot.grid(row=5, column=2)

button_equals = tkinter.Button(root, fg="#000000", text=" / ", width=33, bg="red", font="Calibri 12 bold", command=lambda: add ("/"))
button_equals.grid(row=6, column=0, columnspan=3)

button_equals = tkinter.Button(root, fg="#000000", text="CONVERT TO PERCENTAGE", width=33,bg="red", font="Calibri 12 bold", command=lambda: add ("*100"))
button_equals.grid(row=7, column=0, columnspan=3)

button_equals = tkinter.Button(root, fg="#000000", text=" = ",bg="red", width=33, font="Calibri 12 bold",  command=lambda: calculate())
button_equals.grid(row=8, column=0, columnspan=3)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: hey this is nice, but not helping the problem i have.